# Which end of a pipe is for input and which for output?

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor

Recently I started suspecting that I use the ends of the pipes wrongly:

From the man pages:

> pipe()  creates  a pipe.. ..pipefd[0] refers to the read end of the
>   pipe. pipefd[1] refers to the write end of the pipe.

So in my mind I had it like this:

```
                .---------------------------.
               /                            /\
              | pipedfd[0]       pipedfd[1]|  |
process1 ---> |                            | -----> process2
              | input                output|  |
               \____________________________\/
```

However the code that I have here and works suggests otherwise:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int pipedfd[2];
  char buf[30];

  pipe(pipedfd);
  printf("writing to file descriptor #%d\n", pipedfd[1]);
  write(pipedfd[1], "test", 5);
  printf("reading from file descriptor #%d\n", pipedfd[0]);
  read(pipedfd[0], buf, 5);
  printf("read \"%s\"\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

Namely it writes to the output(?) of the pipe and reads from the input(?) of the pipe?

Comment: Try checking the error return from read and write and it will all become clear.

Comment: Read end of the pipe = where you read from = `pipefd[0]` (not the part you *write* to, as in your diagram). Sounds pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Jon When I think of a physical pipe I think of it as having one corner for input(getting water) and one for output(letting water out). I don't think that the water is going to flow(write) to the output of the pipe. That's against intuition in my mind. And no, I am not a plummer.

Comment: @Pithikos: The physical pipe metaphor really does more harm than good in this case. :)

Comment: The arrows in your diagram are reversed from what they should be.  Draw them pointing the opposite direction.

Comment: @Jon: Actually, the physical metaphor is exactly how it works: you stuff things in on one side (`fd[1]`) and it comes out of the other (`fd[0]`). And if you try to put in too much it blocks until stuff has been taken out again.

Comment: @DarkDust yes but what I was saying is that according to many resources, fd[1] is called "input" and fd[0] is called "output". When you think of a physical pipe you understand the "input" as the corner where pipe itself takes things inside. But with pipe() it's the opposite. Input is where the programmer himself put things. They should either not call it pipe or had reversed the labels IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell, swap the numbers `0` and `1` in your diagram and you got what I'll describe below.

From the Mac OS X man page:

> The pipe() function creates a pipe (an object that allows unidirectional data flow) and allocates a pair of file descriptors.  The first descriptor connects to the read
>        end of the pipe; the second connects to the write end.
>
> Data written to fildes[1] appears on (i.e., can be read from) fildes[0].  This allows the output of one program to be sent to another program: the source's standard out-
>        put is set up to be the write end of the pipe; the sink's standard input is set up to be the read end of the pipe.  The pipe itself persists until all of its associated
>        descriptors are closed.

I'll describe how it's often used, that might clear it up. Imagine you have a process and want to spawn a child, to which you want to send commands.

- First, you call `pipe` and get the two file descriptors.
- Then you call `fork` to create the child.

  - In the child, you close the *writing* file descriptor (`fd[1]`) and leave the *reading* one open.
  - In the parent, you do the reverse: you close the *reading* (`fd[0]`) file descriptor and leave the *writing* one open.
- Now the parent can write into "his" part of the pipe (`fd[1]`) and the child can read on the other (`fd[0]`).

The closing is not necessary but is usually done. If you need two-way communication you either need a second set of file descriptors plus a second call to `pipe`, or you use a two way channel like Unix domain sockets or a named pipe.

Answer (score 2):

The [Linux man page for `pipe`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) disambiguates this as follows:

> Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel
>   until it is read from the read end of the pipe.

That is, you `read` from `fd[0]` and `write` to `fd[1]`

Comment: @JonPurdy: Yes, that's what his code is doing, his diagram (and understanding) are reversed